# AppsScript function results in error "the coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to loop over a sheet, vertically and horizontally, and copy certain values to another sheet. The problem is it won't work due to error "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet". It will appear on the lines with getLastRow() or getLastColumn() methods. Tried fixing with getLastRow() - 1 (response in other post) but doesn't work.

Also, there is no formula filling the cells with "" or similar, just simple text.

The code:

```
function Ordenar_XT() {

  var leidas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT");
  var relevado= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT").getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var idTurma= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT").getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var baseTrainers= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BASEXT");
  var baseContenido = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BASECONTENIDO");


  var XT = leidas.getRange(1, 1, leidas.getLastRow() - 1, leidas.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i=1;i<leidas.getLastRow()+1;i++){

    if(relevado[i]!="Relevado"){

      for(var j=0;j < leidas.getLastColumn()-1;j++){

        if(XT[i][j]=="Estou deixando feedback sobre:" || XT[i][j]=="Estoy dejando feedback sobre:"){

          var last= baseTrainers.getLastRow()+1; 

          baseTrainers.getRange(last, 2).setValue(XT[i][j+1]);
          baseTrainers.getRange(last, 1).setValue(idTurma[i]);

          var formula = baseTrainers.getRange(1,8);

          formula.copyTo(baseTrainers.getRange(last, 8));


          var ok=true;
          var l = 2;
          while(ok && l <=10){

            switch(XT[i][j+l]){

              case "¿Qué tan satisfecho estás con tu XT?": 
              case "Quão satisfeito você ficou com seu XT?": baseTrainers.getRange(last, 3).setValue(XT[i][j+l+1]);
                break;

              case "¿El XT tiene dominio del tema?": 
              case "O XT tinha domínio do tema?": baseTrainers.getRange(last, 4).setValue(XT[i][j+l+1]);
                break;

              case "¿El XT explicó y comunicó los temas correctamente?": 
              case "O XT explicou bem os assuntos?": baseTrainers.getRange(last, 5).setValue(XT[i][j+l+1]);
                break;
              case "¿El XT fue abierto para evacuar dudas?": case "O XT foi aberto para tirar dúvidas?": baseTrainers.getRange(last, 6).setValue(XT[i][j+l+1]);
                break;
              case "¿La cantidad de práctica aplicada por el XT fue suficiente para aprender los procesos?" :
              case"A quantidade de prática aplicada pelo XT foi suficiente para aprender sobre os processos?": baseTrainers.getRange(last, 7).setValue(XT[i][j+l+1]);
                break;
              default: ok=false;
                break; 
            }                 
            l +=2;       
          }       
        }
      }     
    } 
  }  
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks Cooper, I add the section of the code with the changes:

```
var XT = leidas.getRange(1, 1, leidas.getLastRow() - 1, leidas.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<XT.length;i++){

    if(relevado[i]!="Relevado"){

      for(var j=0;j < XT[i].length;j++){

        if(XT[i][j]=="Estou deixando feedback sobre:" || XT[i][j]=="Estoy dejando feedback sobre:"){

          var last= baseTrainers.getRange(); 

          baseTrainers.getRange(last, 2).setValue(XT[i][j+1]);
          baseTrainers.getRange(last, 1).setValue(idTurma[i]);

          var formula = baseTrainers.getRange(1,8);

          formula.copyTo(baseTrainers.getRange(last, 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looping starts at 1 `var i=1;i<leidas.getLastRow()+1;i++`

but your data:

```
var relevado= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT").getRange("A:A").getValues();
var idTurma= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de datos REPXT").getRange("B:B").getValues();
```

Is in the form of a 2d array so you will always miss the first row of data and run out of array elements at the end.

Instead of looping through the rows, try looping through the data.  Start your for loop at zero or use the array forEach method.

Start with something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<relevado.length;i++)
```

Also getting data by using ranges like this: `getRange("A:A").getValues()` can lead to large numbers of nulls at the end of data.  Try using `getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Cooper.  This solves the problem with the rows, what would you do to solve the getLastColumn problem? and the error also happens while obtaining the last row on the sheet I want to copy the data too, I have to know the last one +1 cause this is the row where the data is going to be copied.

Comment: You shouldn't be using columns to increment through data arrays.  If you loop through a 2d say data, the row loop is  `for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)` and the column loop is `for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;i++)` or you can use `data.forEach(r){r.foreach(c){})})`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! The problem I can't solve now is getting the last free row of the sheet I want to copy the data to: var last= baseTrainers.getLastRow()+1; any idea?

Comment: Updated the post!

Comment: Change this `var XT = leidas.getRange(1, 1, leidas.getLastRow() - 1, leidas.getLastColumn()).getValues()` to this `var XT = leidas.getRange(1, 1, leidas.getLastRow() , leidas.getLastColumn()).getValues()`  or more simply `var XT=leadas.getDataRange().getValues()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205635/discussion-between-marcos-alejandro-perez-and-cooper).